# Check Docker image and Docker file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

How can I quickly check if there is any diff between `my-docker-image:latest` and given `Dockerfile`? I'm looking for command like

```
$ docker image diff my-docker-image:latest path/to/Dockerfile
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: What would you do if they're different?  `docker build` is usually pretty quick if the source tree isn't changed at all (as for that matter is `docker pull`).

Comment: Yes it is pretty quick I just don't like a lot of output that docker build generates. I can use --quit option of course, but in this case I don't see what docker do when actually build something. So I actually want behavior "no actual job done -> no spam in output".